# Is the function injective if the Jacobian has full column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n: x \to f(x)$ be a continuous and differentiable function with $m < n$. If the Jacobian $J_f$ has full column rank (i.e., rank=$m$) $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, does this imply that $f$ is an injective function? If yes, can I get a reference for this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $f(t) =\pmatrix{ \sin t\\ \cos t}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is such function $f$ locally injective? [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664294/local-injectivity-given-rank-of-jacobian)

Comment: yes......................