# Prove that the image of a $C^r$ function with derivative of maximum rank is a $k$-manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, differential-topology

**Definition**

A $k$-manifold with $k>0$ in $\Bbb R^n$ of class $C^r$ is a subspace $M$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that for any $y\in  M$ there exists an open set $V$ of $M$ containing $y$, and open set $U$ in either $\Bbb R^k$ or $H^k$ and a continuous map $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ carrying $U$ onto $V$ in one-to-one fashion such that

1. $\alpha$ is of class $C^r$;
2. $\alpha^{-1}:V\rightarrow U$ is continuous;
3. $D\alpha(x)$ has rank $k$ for each $x\in U$.

The map $\alpha$ is called a coordinate patch on $M$ about $y$.

Well I ask to prove that If $f$ is a function defined in a open set $A$ of $\Bbb R^k$ with values in $\Bbb R^n$ and with derivative $Df(x)$ of rank $k$ at each point $x$ of $A$ then the set $M:=f[A]$ is a $k$-manifold.

So by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664294/local-injectivity-given-rank-of-jacobian) relevant result we know that the map $f$ is locally injective and so any element $x$ of $A$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ where $f$ is injective so that we have only to prove that the set $f[U_x]$ is open in $M$ and so that the local inverse of $f$ at $U_x$ is continuous but unfortunately I do not able to do it. So could someone help me, please?

**MY ATTEMPT**

So by the link I posted I know there exist $i_1,...,i_k=1,...,n$ such that the function
$$
\phi:=\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}\circ f
$$
is a local diffeomorphism where $\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}$ is a function from $\Bbb R^n$ onto $\Bbb R^k$ defined through the equation
$$
\big[\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}(x)\big](h):=x(i_h)
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and for any $h=1,...,k$. So for any $x\in A$ there exist a open neighborhood $U_x$ where $\phi$ is injective and so $f$ too. Now by the continuity of $\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}$ the set
$$
V_{f(x)}:=\pi^{-1}_{i_1,...,i_k}\Big[\phi[U_x]\Big]\cap M
$$
is an open neighborhood of $f(x)$ in $M$ so observig that
$$
y\in f[U_x]\Rightarrow\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}(y)\in\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}\Big[f[U_x]\Big]=\phi[U_x]\Rightarrow y\in\pi^{-1}_{i_1,...,i_k}\Big[\phi[U_x]\Big]\cap M=V_{f(x)}\Rightarrow f[U_x]\subseteq V_{f(x)}\Rightarrow U_x=f^{-1}\Big[f[U_x]\Big]\subseteq f^{-1}[V_{f(x)}]
$$
so that the statement folows showing that
$$
V_y:=f[U_x]
$$
because in this case the continuous function $\phi^{-1}\circ\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}$ would be the inverse of $f$ at $U_x$. So in this case we observe that
$$
y\in f^{-1}[V_{f(x)}]\Rightarrow f(y)\in V_{f(x)}\Rightarrow \phi(y)=\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}\big(f(y)\big)\in\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}[V_y]\subseteq\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}\Biggl[\pi^{-1}_{i_1,...,i_k}\Big[\phi[U_x]\Big]\Biggl]=\phi[U_x]\Rightarrow\phi\Big[f^{-1}[V_{f(x)}]\Big]\subseteq\phi[U_x]\Rightarrow f^{-1}[V_{f(x)}]\subseteq U_x
$$
and thus we conclude that
$$
f^{-1}[V_{f(x)}]=U_x
$$
and so the statement follows. But I am not sure about the correctdness of the proof of the last inclusion. So are my arguments correct?

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove is not true. For example, consider the map $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $f(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t)$. Its image is shaped like a figure-eight in the plane, which is not a manifold.

Comment: @JackLee Oh, thanks very much for the counterexample! I am really surprised about: could you briefly (if it is possible naturally) explain why $f$ is not a manifold?

Comment: One way to see it is to note that the complement of the origin is a $1$-manifold, so if the image is going to be a manifold, it has to have dimension $1$. In a smooth $1$-manifold, the velocities of curves through a given point span a $1$-dimensional space; but in the figure-eight there are two smooth curves through the origin that have linearly independent velocities.

Comment: Oh yeah! The tangent space at the origin has dimension two. So a last question: could you briefly (if this do not bother you naturally) indicate where my arguments fail? I like to learn by my mistakes: understanding them I hope then a next time they do not misdirect me, that's all. Anyway thanks very much for your assistance !!!

Comment: It's not true that the tangent space at the origin has dimension $2$ -- there isn't a whole $2$-dimensional space of tangent vectors there; there's just a union of two lines. In some sense, the point is that the set of tangent vectors doesn't form a vector space.

Comment: The problem with your argument is that you seem to be treating $\phi^{-1}$ as a function. But if $\phi$ is not injective, then there is no such function.

Comment: Oh yeah, I understand. The function $\phi$ is not generally injective but if by the link I post the function $\phi$ is injective in $U_x$ then the function $\phi^{-1}$ is defined in $\phi[U_x]$ and $\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}[V_{f(x)}]$ is just here contained so that the (continuous) function $\phi^{-1}\circ\pi_{i_1,...,i_k}:V_{f(x)}\rightarrow U_x$ is defined, that's all.